# i have an one issue with my sql query ..like i need multiple row data in to one row

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

```
id date aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg
1  23   222  0   0   0  0    0   0
1  23    0   222  0  0  0    0   0
1  23    0   0   333  0  0    0   0
```

like this i have 7 rows, i need only the values in one row.

Comment: And what would that row look like?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want aggregation:

```
select id, date, max(aaa), max(bbb), max(ccc), max(ddd), max(eee), max(fff), max(ggg)
from t
group by id, date;
```

This type of "multi-lined" result set is often produced by a bad `group by` query.  If that is the case, you should ask a *new* question about actually fixing the query.